# exponential representation of 3 dimensional rotations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, rotations, matrix-calculus

[image]

This is a problem I am stuck at. I can't find appropriate matrices for a). They must be linked to Pauli matrices but I can't find a way to extend Pauli matrices to 3 dimensional space. Could anyone suggest me what the matrices are?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For the first one, the matrix is 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

Now you have to work out why exp of that really is the thing you want, and do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Well,
$$iL_1=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0}.$$
I'll leave you to work out the others.
(Why do physicists have to strew everything with $i$s?)

Comment: Could you tell me what you mean by $is$?

Comment: And I think $L_1$ itself is the matrix you gave. Anyway I will work those details out.

Comment: I believe that Lord means "occurrences of $i$, the square root of $-1$."